# How do I add up values in a json file in python?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot to manage a fundraising event in my school. It stores user information in a json file. (Name, How much they donated, etc.) I want to make a command that goes through the json file and adds up donations from each individual user, so I can get the total amount of money raised.

My json file looks like this:

```json
{
   "blacklist":[
      
   ],
   "users":{
      "822679038434213908":{
         "grade":"",
         "paid":15,
         "name":"John Doe",
         "manager":true
      }
   }
}
```

How would I make it so that it adds up the information of each user (stored under `paid`) in python and return it?

Comment: Can you post a complete object. Which includes multiple user details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show how this works, i've added a second user to your json.

The below code example just loops through the users in the json and grabs each user's donation amount and adds it to the sum - finally printing the sum.

```
json_input = {
   "blacklist":[
      
   ],
   "users":{
      "822679038434213908":{
         "grade":"",
         "paid":15,
         "name":"John Doe",
         "manager":'true'
      },
      "822679038434213909":{
         "grade":"",
         "paid":20,
         "name":"John Doe",
         "manager":'true'
      }
   }
}

sum = 0
for user in json_input['users']:
    sum += json_input['users'][user]['paid']

print(sum)
```